# Using PHP with PostgreSQL instead of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

NOTE: This is not about which better database, not at all.

Hi, my client has a shared host with the following stack:
PHP: 7.x.x
MySQL: 5.6.x
Postgres: 9.2.x
PhpMyAdmin
PhpPgAdmin

I'm able to use both MySQL(PHP) and PostgreSQL(C#, Go, Python, JS), but I personally prefer Postgres, also my client's host specs make it harder to use some SQL features like CTE which have no support in MySQL 5.6 (I know 8.0 has them).

The problem:
I plan to use Postgres, but I'm a little concerned about the combination of PHP+Postgres, since it seems that most PHP development is coupled with MySQL, for example, PhpMyAdmin is activly developed compared to PhpPgAdmin (the last release from 2018), also it seems it ALWAYS assumed that PHP runs using MySQL while Postgres is like a second citizen.

So, in your experience, should I go with Postgres or MySQL, to minimize the trouble that may arise?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this belongs in stackoverflow. Try https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used php with postgresql for about 20 years off and on. The driver is stable enough. You lack built-in support for some of the fancier data types in PostgreSQL (or used to anyway) - ranges, arrays etc.